# How to insert a null value for INT in database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am not using HTML form to get values for this query. I am just inserting a second query once user creates a specific record. However, the second query is not inserting '0' unless I change it to VARCHAR. Others are working fine except for number.

```
$null = null;
    $query2="insert into npi_program2 (prodID,prodName,TPM,scheme,phases,status,number,date,remarkProg) 
             values('$prodID','$prodName','$null','$null','$null', 0 ,DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%b-%d-%Y'),'$null')";
    
    $res1=$db->query($query2);
```

Comment: You could set the `DEFAULT` value of the column to `NULL`

Comment: Add quote chars in `$null = 'null';` (the value must be string, not predefined PHP constant) and remove them in `.. , $null, ..` (the value must be inserted as predefined MySQL constant, not as string literal).

Comment: it still isnt able to insert into the database unless I make it as VarChar. Why is it so ?

Comment: Do you ever bother to check for errors? When a query fails, your system will tell you why. What are you using, `mysqli` or `PDO`?

Comment: There is no error popping. It just inserts for the first query but doesnt for the second(the script above). im using mysqli

Answer (score 0):

0 is not equal to null. 0 is false. To insert null in the database, you should pass `NULL` as a value.

```
    $query2="insert into npi_program2 (prodID,prodName,TPM,scheme,phases,status,number,date,remarkProg) 
             values($prodID,$prodName,NULL,NULL,NULL, 0 ,DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%b-%d-%Y'),NULL)";
    
    $res1=$db->query($query2)
```

Comment: It still is not inserting into the database. Why is it so?